# File upload Error : FlaskRestful - Getting 400 for POST request

Tags: rest, flask, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I am trying to upload a file through the post request in flask restfulplus

[I followed the example in this link](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html)

Here is my code

```
@ns.route('/upload/logo/')
@ns.doc('Upload Logo')
class UploadImage(Resource):
    @ns.param('picture', 'image file path')
    # @ns.route('/upload/')
    def post(self):
        parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parse.add_argument('picture', type=FileStorage, location='files', required=True)
        argsd = parse.parse_args()
        print(argsd)
        imgFile = argsd['picture']
        print(imgFile)
        imgFile.save("your_file_name.jpg")
        return {'successfully' : 'loaded'}
```

For some reason the file is not getting uploaded. Can someone help me to solve this problem.
[Input Upload][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQc4W.png[image]

Comment: I don't have any experience in python, so I might be mistaken. In your code, you are not uploading an image. You are only sending the *image path* as a string to server. This is why validation fails. Your payload does not contain the image binary. Look for using multipart request in flask-rest

Comment: I uploaded the file through post man and tried to make a request. It is still failing giving the error response as input payload validation failed.

Comment: According to the documentation you just have to send the path of the file on your file system. The request is made along with the file @Aboodz